# Ubuntu 21.10 external monitor via USB-C will only mirror, not extend

Tags: nvidia, display, usb-c

I have a Thunderbolt 4 laptop and I purchased a USB-C to HDMI apadter. In ubuntu, the display will only work on mirror mode, and not in extended mode (Join Displays). I have a nvidia card on the laptop.

I know the hardware is good because I have dual boot and it works flawlessly in Windows.

I also bought a Razer Thunderbolt 4 docking station. Same problem occurs. Works on windows, not on ubuntu, obnly in mirroed mode.

**[EDIT]**

Also, just realized that event in single monitor, if I select the usb-c monitor (via adapter or docking station) it will also wont't work, only when mirroed.

**[EDIT 2]**
I have posted this problem in the nvidia problem, and following some instruction I realized that it also occurs if I set intel in the `prime-select` meaning this is probable not nvidia related.

**Information**

Driver: nvidia-driver-510 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.21.10.1

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

xrandr

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.16*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00 + 144.00*  120.00   119.88    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5986:2127 Acer, Inc HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2386:434b Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c55 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 005: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 1532:0f30 Razer USA, Ltd USB3.1 Hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 8087:0b40 Intel Corp. USB3.0 Hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 011: ID 1532:122e Razer USA, Ltd Thunderbolt 4 Dock
Bus 005 Device 010: ID 1532:053d Razer USA, Ltd USB Audio
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 1532:0f21 Razer USA, Ltd RAZER THUNDERBOLT 4 DOCK CHROMA
Bus 005 Device 008: ID 046d:085b Logitech, Inc. Logitech Webcam C925e
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 046d:0aaa Logitech, Inc. PRO X
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1532:0f2f Razer USA, Ltd USB2.0 Hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0bda:2172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. BillBoard Device
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1d5c:5801 Fresco Logic USB2.0 Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I just upgraded to 21.10. Same problem

Comment: Did you already install the proprietary Nvidia drivers? `sudo apt update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Yes. I tried that.

Comment: To whoever close-voted, please retract the close votes, because OP 21.10 is on topic

Comment: Yes, I have originally posted as 21.04, but I saw the first comment, updated ubuntu, updated drivers and the problem persisted, so I changed the version on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The weird thing in your output is:

```
DP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
```

Because `eDP-1-1`, your laptop's display, should always be `primary`, not the external monitor.

You could try tweaking your BIOS as they did in this Q&A:

- [xrandr overrides --panning setting for HDMI display](https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-xrandr-overrides-panning-setting-for-hdmi-display.29898/)

One tip to shorten your journey is to use:

```
$ xrandr | grep " connected "

HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

Then all the disconnected monitors don't show up!

Another tip, is that even after your system is working, sometimes things will go "flakey". It's good to have a function to reset `panning` and other options. For example, on my system:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep xreset -A10

xreset () {

    # Reset xrandr to normal, first use: xrandr | grep " connected "
    # HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
    # eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    # DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --fb 1920x1080   --panning 1920x1080 \
           --output DP-1-1  --mode 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0    --rotate normal \
           --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x2160 --rotate normal \
           --primary
--
} # xreset
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, was just a matter of putting the right frequency on the display configuration.

I used my wife's display via ubs-C and the image was messed up, but I had some image. That got me thinking about the frequency, so I adjusted and it worked there. I tried the same thing on my dock station and it worked!

Monitor is 144Hz so the frequency needed to be adjusted.